# what to call a matrix that has no zero entries?

Tags: matrices, terminology

what is the technical term of a matrix that has no zero entries. I suspect the name is dense but not sure. Could anyone confirm that?

Comment: “Dense” just means that most of the entries are nonzero, not that all the entries are nonzero. (And “dense” is not a precise term in this context.) I don’t know a word that means “all entries are nonzero”, so you might need to introduce your own term for this.

Comment: @littleO Thanks.

Comment: It is called an “entrywise/elementwise nonzero matrix”. The term “dense matrix” means something else. It refers to a square or rectangular matrix with few (in proportion) or no zero elements.

Comment: @user1551 you could write it as an answer so that I approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called an “entrywise/elementwise nonzero matrix”. The term “dense matrix” means something else: it refers to a square or rectangular matrix with no or proportionately few zero elements.

Answer (score 1):

In numerical analysis and scientific computing, a sparse matrix or sparse array is a matrix in which most of the elements are zero.

The opposite of a sparse matrix, where the majority of its values are non-zero, is called a dense matrix.